# Calculate rolling maximal consecutive drawdown

Tags: python, algorithm

Given several time series of daily stock price changes, calculate every day the rolling maximal consecutive drawdown (without any rises in between) in the recent n days. For example, if the recent 7 days' price change sequence is `[-3, -4, 9, -1, 1, -1, -3]`, the rolling maximal consecutive drawdown of this window would be -7.

The code input is an m*n matrix, representing the time series of n stocks' price changes. k is the lookback days.

Comment: Don't understand - are there prices in `array`?

Comment: @MBo No those are price changes. For example, [1, -2] stands for the stock goes up for 1 dollar and then drops down for 2 dollars

Comment: Why is it -7 instead of -12 from `-5, 0, -3, -4`?  The 0 isn't a rise...

Comment: @btilly I personally agree with you but for this question it only considers negative numbers.

Answer (score 0):

**Update**
This answers the question of computing a running drawdown, but I forgot to include the windowing aspect.

I believe the following `NumPy` code computes the running drawdown as you have specified. Maybe the last row of the expected output given in the question is not correct?

The strategy is to first compute a standard cumulative sum with the positive values replaced by zeros. Each drawdown run in this series has the correct changes intra-drawdown run, but the values are offset by the initial value of the cumulative sum just prior to the run. The second step is to compute the offsets by identifying the transitions immediately preceding a drawdown and sliding those values to match up with the subsequent drawdown run.

The code may be a more concise explanation.

### Sample Code

Start with the sample data from the question.

```py
x = array([[  0,   9],
       [ -5, -10],
       [  9,   9],
       [ -6,  -9],
       [  7,   3],
       [  4,   3],
       [  4,   3],
       [  1,  -3],
       [ -2,  -4],
       [ -6,  -5],
       [  4,  -2],
       [ -2,   0],
       [  2,  -3],
       [  2,   3],
       [ -2,   7],
       [ -6,   8],
       [ -5,   6],
       [ -4,  -6],
       [  2,   8],
       [-10,  -5]])
```

Next, compute the cumulative sum with zero's for the non-negative values.

```py
>>> s = x.clip(max=0).cumsum(0)
>>> s
array([[  0,   0],
       [ -5, -10],
       [ -5, -10],
       [-11, -19],
       [-11, -19],
       [-11, -19],
       [-11, -19],
       [-11, -22],
       [-13, -26],
       [-19, -31],
       [-19, -33],
       [-21, -33],
       [-21, -36],
       [-21, -36],
       [-23, -36],
       [-29, -36],
       [-34, -36],
       [-38, -42],
       [-38, -42],
       [-48, -47]])
```

Compute a mask that has a `1` just before the start of each negative drawdown run.

```py
>>> t = np.diff(1*(x<0),axis=0,append=0).clip(0)
>>> t
array([[1, 1],
       [0, 0],
       [1, 1],
       [0, 0],
       [0, 0],
       [0, 0],
       [0, 1],
       [1, 0],
       [0, 0],
       [0, 0],
       [1, 0],
       [0, 1],
       [0, 0],
       [1, 0],
       [0, 0],
       [0, 0],
       [0, 1],
       [0, 0],
       [1, 1],
       [0, 0]])
```

Take the product of the mask and the cumulative sum, fill in the zeros and roll the entire array forward one position. These are the offsets we need to subtract from the cumulative sum.

```py
>>> d = np.roll(np.minimum.accumulate(t * s), 1, axis=0)
>>> d[0,:] = 0
>>> d
array([[. 0,   0],
       [  0,   0],
       [  0,   0],
       [ -5, -10],
       [ -5, -10],
       [ -5, -10],
       [ -5, -10],
       [ -5, -19],
       [-11, -19],
       [-11, -19],
       [-11, -19],
       [-19, -19],
       [-19, -33],
       [-19, -33],
       [-21, -33],
       [-21, -33],
       [-21, -33],
       [-21, -36],
       [-21, -36],
       [-38, -42]])
```

Subtract the offsets from the cumulative sum to get the result.

```py
>>> s - d
array([[  0,   0],
       [ -5, -10],
       [ -5, -10],
       [ -6,  -9],
       [ -6,  -9],
       [ -6,  -9],
       [ -6,  -9],
       [ -6,  -3],
       [ -2,  -7],
       [ -8, -12],
       [ -8, -14],
       [ -2, -14],
       [ -2,  -3],
       [ -2,  -3],
       [ -2,  -3],
       [ -8,  -3],
       [-13,  -3],
       [-17,  -6],
       [-17,  -6],
       [-10,  -5]])
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort! But this solution doesn't work. I think the hardest part is how to keep adjusting the consecutive drawdowns at both ends of the window and get the max consecutive drawdown in the window (there might be many (more than 2) consecutive negative sequences in a window) while the window is moving

Comment: @royalgrasshopper Yes, I got so focused on computing the running drawdown that I missed with windowing aspect. I will post another answer for the windowing.

Answer (score 0):

The following shows how to use `NumPy` to compute the minimum running drawdown as defined in the question over a sliding window.

This first `python` transcript demonstrates how to compute a running drawdown for a single series of changes. The strategy can be broken into the following steps:

- mask - mark the negative elements in the series.
- cum_drawdowns - compute the cumulative drawdown
- end_mask - differentiate the mask to find the end of each drawdown
- offsets - compute the offsets to correct the cumulative drawdown
- drawdowns - adjust the cumulative drawdown by the offset

```py
>>> data
array([  0,  -5,   9,  -6,   7,   4,   4,   1,  -2,  -6,   4,  -2,   2,
         2,  -2,  -6,  -5,  -4,   2, -10])
>>> mask = 1 * (data < 0)
>>> mask
array([0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1])
>>> cum_drawdowns = (mask * data).cumsum()
>>> cum_drawdowns
array([  0,  -5,  -5, -11, -11, -11, -11, -11, -13, -19, -19, -21, -21,
       -21, -23, -29, -34, -38, -38, -48])
>>> end_mask = 1 * (np.diff(mask, prepend=0) < 0)
>>> end_mask
array([0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0])
>>> offsets = np.minimum.accumulate(end_mask * cum_drawdowns)
>>> offsets
array([  0,   0,  -5,  -5, -11, -11, -11, -11, -11, -11, -19, -19, -21,
       -21, -21, -21, -21, -21, -38, -38])
>>> offsets
array([  0,   0,  -5,  -5, -11, -11, -11, -11, -11, -11, -19, -19, -21,
       -21, -21, -21, -21, -21, -38, -38])
>>> drawdowns = cum_drawdowns - offsets
>>> drawdowns
array([  0,  -5,   0,  -6,   0,   0,   0,   0,  -2,  -8,   0,  -2,   0,
         0,  -2,  -8, -13, -17,   0, -10])
>>> drawdowns.min()
-17
```

The following `python` transcript shows how to apply this strategy over sliding windows. The key step is using [`np.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view`](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view.html) which provides a view of the original data as a series of windows of the specified length. This is accomplished by manipulating the strides and still pointing to the original data.

The strategy can be broken into the following steps:

- xdata - prepend the data with `k-1` zeros for the correct windowing shape
- windows - construct the windowed view
- mask - construct the mask for negative elements
- cum_drawdowns - compute the cumulative drawdowns
- end_mask - construct the mask marking the end of each drawdown
- offsets - compute the corrections for the cumulative drawdowns
- take the minimum across each window to get the result.

```py
>>> xdata
array([[  0,   0],
       [  0,   0],
       [  0,   0],
       [  0,   0],
       [  0,   9],
       [ -5, -10],
       [  9,   9],
       [ -6,  -9],
       [  7,   3],
       [  4,   3],
       [  4,   3],
       [  1,  -3],
       [ -2,  -4],
       [ -6,  -5],
       [  4,  -2],
       [ -2,   0],
       [  2,  -3],
       [  2,   3],
       [ -2,   7],
       [ -6,   8],
       [ -5,   6],
       [ -4,  -6],
       [  2,   8],
       [-10,  -5]])
>>> windows = np.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view(xdata, 5, 0)
>>> windows.shape
(20, 2, 5)
>>> mask = 1 * (windows < 0)
>>> cum_drawdowns = (mask * windows).cumsum(axis=2)
>>> end_mask = 1 * (np.diff(mask, prepend=0, axis=2) < 0)
>>> offsets = np.minimum.accumulate(end_mask * cum_drawdowns, axis=2)
>>> (cum_drawdowns - offsets).min(axis=2)
array([[  0,   0],
       [ -5, -10],
       [ -5, -10],
       [ -6, -10],
       [ -6, -10],
       [ -6, -10],
       [ -6,  -9],
       [ -6,  -9],
       [ -2,  -7],
       [ -8, -12],
       [ -8, -14],
       [ -8, -14],
       [ -8, -11],
       [ -6,  -7],
       [ -2,  -3],
       [ -8,  -3],
       [-13,  -3],
       [-17,  -6],
       [-17,  -6],
       [-15,  -6]])
```

Comment: @royalgrasshopper If you round this answer useful, can you accept it?